# Installing flash on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, flash, aptitude

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.10 and I'd like to install Flash Player on it. However, when I try to install it as follows, I'm unable to. Some hint on how I could proceed? Thanks.

```
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package flashplugin-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'flashplugin-installer' has no installation candidate
```

I haven't set up VNC yet, so I'd very much prefer a CLI solution for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled sufficent sources of software? Since you want to install Flash via the CLI, you will have to edit your sources.list found here: `/etc/apt/sources.list`. To do so, you'll have to use `sudo` and a suitable editor such as `nano` **after backing up the original file**:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu to ensure that the sources you need are included. For example:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

You can read more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Once you've edited sources.list to your satisfaction, you will need to refresh things and make `apt` aware of the changes by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You should then be able to install Flash Player with

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Greetings, @Zanna It seems the recommended method is using [`adobe-flashplugin`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash), and in fact [the page leading on from that](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash) has [a screenshot where `flashplugin-installer` is removed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=software-center-remove-conflicts.png). Is this information still relevant?

Comment: @Seb I doubt it - I think this information is obsolete :( alas it's not my post - I just edited it to improve the formatting