# chrome flash plugin crash on ubuntu 14.0

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, flash

I have ubuntu 14.04 running the latest chrome browser version 40. The flash player crashes every time I try to play video in chrome. I am not sure what caused these issues to crop up suddenly since it was all fine till few weeks back. Any suggestion on how to get flash plugin working again in chrome? I do have pepper flash player installed separately but I guess chrome uses it's own flash version.

Comment: Get what working exactly? Video playback in Chrome or video sound in Chromium and/or Firefox? The two questions are most likely only loosely related, so it would be better to create a new question for one of them and [edit] this one.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/253292/installing-flash-on-ubuntu

Comment: The latest update of chrome seem to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, type chrome:plugins in the address bar to open the Plug-ins page and on the Plug-ins page that appears, find the "Flash" listing.

To enable Adobe Flash Player, click the Enable link under its name.

To disable Adobe Flash Player completely, click the Disable link under its name.

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en